# Phone verification service in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Almost every web applications are in the need of verifying phone numbers entered by their customers.

Is there any phone verification service (like the one offered by Twilio) in Amazon Web Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Amazon AWS doesn't do this. They don't really deal with telephony.